# math coding simple fix needed

Tags: javascript, math

I need some help, I would like to achieve that when the user selects level 2, the numbers in the equation get larger. I am unsure how to code that, it should be very quick to solve, thanks.

```
<html>

<select id="mySelect">
<option id="Level1">Level 1</option> // selecting level 2 should make the equations harder 
<option id="Level2">Level 2</option>

</select>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="INlist(10)">Start!</button>
<p id="demo6"></p>

<script>
var num1 = [];
var num2 = [];
var ans = [];
var msum = [];
function INlist(count)
{
   document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = ""
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      num1[i] = 0;
      num2[i] = 0;
      ans[i] = 0;
      msum[i] = 0;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      num1[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9); // these two lines decide how large the numbers are
      num2[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*9); 
      ans[i] = num1[i] + num2[i];

      msum[i] = num1[i] + " + " + num2[i] + " = "
      + "<input id=\"resp" + i + "\" onchange=\"check(this.value)\"    type=\"text\" name=\"fname\"><br>";

      document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = document.getElementById  ("demo6").innerHTML + msum[i];
   }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

If you want help, try to be more clear about what you are trying to achieve. If you can find an example online, make a code snippet, and/or provide sample outputs you will get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to make the numbers larger as stated in the question, then you should replace the `Math.random()*9` with something more like this:

```
var difficultyModifier = 9;
var level = 2;

num1[i] = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(difficultyModifier * level);
```

In `C#`, I would call `difficultyModifier` a `constant`, though I'm not sure what the equivalent is in JavaScript. The basic idea is that you can multiply your random value (9, in your case) by the level to increase the value.

This will continue to work regardless of how many levels you add, at least until you overflow the max `int` value.